# R trim blocks in binary vector to only first element

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have a binary vector like this (as a column in a dataframe):

`000001111111000111100000001111000011111`

I want to take each block of 1's, and replace the entire block with 0's retaining only the first instance of a 1:

`000001000000000100000000001000000010000`

Currently I'm doing this using what I think is a very inefficient method, and the method is only partially complete. I'm looping through every row of the dataframe and checking for a block start, then storing the index/time associated with that starting 1 in a new dataframe:

```
stepStarts = data.frame()
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$step[i] == 1 & df$step[i-1] == 0){
    stepStarts <- rbind(stepStarts, data.frame(trialNum = df$trialNum[i], stepTime = df$time[i]))
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this without having to loop through a dataframe, and storing the times in a new dataframe (I just want to replace the existing column)?

Comment: `df$step[c(0, diff(df$step)) != 1] <- 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the difference of the vector and mark the positive changes indicating where 0 lead to 1:

```
res <- c(0,diff(x)==1)
```

Check answer:

```
ans <- "000001000000000100000000001000000010000"
ans2 <- paste(res, collapse="")
all.equal(ans, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This falls over if `x` starts with a series of `1`s - I think `(diff(c(0,x)) == 1) + 0` should do it though.